Safari Web Inspector not showing all elements
I am trying to debug something on our Angular app in Safari.  When I open the Inspector, its not showing me the elements inside this div. How can I get Safari to show them? is the inspector loading before the elements or something?
In Chrome, Firefox, and Edge Inspector I can see and inspect all the elements.
I attached a screenshot of the Element inspector in the exact same spot, one in Safari and one in Edge.
What I see in Safari:

What I see in Edge:

I've tried quitting and reopening safari, refreshing, checking the settings
I'm expecting the elements to show up normally like they do in other browsers
